# how would I go about accessing a deep value using a single variable in bracket notation?

Tags: javascript, variables

I am wondering how to do the following- I have the following data:

```
dta = {
       "fielddata": {
           "text1": "4B030C2E-3D53-4DF8-A3535EF377B45DE5",
           "text2": "Unlabeled"
       }
}
```

Which I can access using bracket notation like so

```
var result = dta["fielddata"]["text1"];
```

no problem there, And I can use variables like so

```
var val1 = "fielddata",
    val2 = "text1",
    acc = dta[val1][val2];

log(acc);
```

again, terrific- but how about when I only have a single variable holding the dot notation?

like, what if I only have

```
var val = "fielddata.text1",
    acc = dta[val];
log(acc);
```

This would yield an undefined. 
Any thoughts on how to go about this?

Thanks alot!
Marco

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var val = "fielddata.text1",
    acc = dta,               // reference the base object
    parts = val.split('.'),  // split the val into an Array of individual parts
    i;

  // Iterate the parts, updating acc each time
for( i = 0; i < parts.length; i++ )
    acc = acc[parts[i]];
```

Comment: this is perfect for getting, but how would you alter ?

Answer (score 2):

Another option is [JSONPath](http://code.google.com/p/jsonpath/). For relatively simple usecases, doing it manually is likely a better solution, but with greater complexity, I might use something more formalized.

*And while I hate to suggest it, there's always `eval('dta.fielddata.text1')`*

Comment: I don't think that JSONPath would help in this case.  He wants to get the data out of what would be the path itself, not use the path to get data out of another object.

Comment: @Pointy I'm not sure what that means; OP wants the data at `fielddata.text1`, which is what things like EL and path expressions do.

Comment: Ah OK, I misunderstood the question.  Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

getter

```
exports.getDeep = function(field, object){
  var parts = field.split('.');
  var value = object;
  // Iterate the parts, updating value each time
  for( var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++ ){
      value = value[parts[i]];
      if(i==parts.length-1){
        return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(value))
      }
  }
}
```

setter

```
exports.setDeep = function(field, object, newvalue){
  var parts = field.split('.');
  for( var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++ ){
      if(i==parts.length-1){
        object[parts[i]] = newvalue
        return object
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: damn the setter doesn't work after all, still looking for the answer